# Handling date format in swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

The timestamp from the php rest service is coming out in string format:

```
2016-06-08 09:03:59
```

How to convert it to NSDate in my iOS code. Swift answer preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
// Initialize Date string
var dateStr = "2016-06-08 09:03:59"

// Set date format
var dateFmt = NSDateFormatter()
dateFmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
dateFmt.dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

// Get NSDate for the given string
var date = dateFmt.dateFromString(dateStr)

print(date!)
```

Date is now of type NSDate.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I needed.